# Tiling tile buffer in an Image buffer Index calculation issue

Tags: c#, image-processing, textures

I have a problem in tiling an image buffer with tile buffer of square size. 
Kindly point, what i am doing wrong.

the Idea is to get a image buffer filled with predefined square Tile buffer with some condition. so that output image buffer is properly tilled with Tile, keeping in mind, the image can be rectangular (not square)

Thank you.

I have tried this.

```
static int imgwidth = 150; static int imgheight=100;
    static int gl_fxf = 4;//4*n
    byte[] img_byte8rgbbuff = new byte[imgwidth*imgheight*3];// variable size
    byte[] tile_byte8rgbbuff = new byte[gl_fxf * gl_fxf * 3];// can be of any size 4nX4n

    public byte[] fillwithtile(byte[] in_Image, byte[] Tile)

    {
        byte[] img_byte8rgbbuff_OUT = new byte[in_Image.Length];


        int someMainIndex;


        Action<int, int, int> TFfxMethod = (int a_h, int b_w, int in_indx) =>
        {

            int t_indx;
            //int t_indx2;

            int counter = 0;

            for (int j = a_h; j < a_h + gl_fxf; j++)
                for (int i = b_w; i < b_w + gl_fxf; i++)
                {
                    t_indx = j * 3 * imgwidth + i * 3;
                    // SOMETHING WRONG IN INDEX CALCULATION FOR ARRAYS
                    if (in_Image[in_indx] == 255)// EX. some condition in_Image[in_indx] == 255 RED component
                    {
                        img_byte8rgbbuff_OUT[t_indx] = Tile[counter];
                        img_byte8rgbbuff_OUT[t_indx+1] = Tile[counter+1];
                        img_byte8rgbbuff_OUT[t_indx+2] = Tile[counter+2];

                    }
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }

        };


        for (int palboxH = 0; palboxH <= imgheight; palboxH = palboxH + gl_fxf)
            for (int palboxW = 0; palboxW <= imgwidth; palboxW = palboxW + gl_fxf)
            {

                someMainIndex = palboxH * 3 * gl_fxf * imgwidth + palboxW * 3 * gl_fxf;

                TFfxMethod(palboxH, palboxW, someMainIndex);


            }
return img_byte8rgbbuff_OUT;

    }//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself

counter should be following code 
and no need for in_indx

```
 counter = counter +3;
```

Comment: Since you figured it out, go ahead and mark your answer as the answer. Then everyone will know this is not an unanswered question.